# Snowflake EXPLAIN query support with Snowflake JDBC Driver

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to run an EXPLAIN snowflake query through the JDBC driver with the Snowflake extension? I am running `net.snowflake    snowflake-jdbc  3.12.8` and it throws an error saying `net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 15 unexpected 'EXPLAIN'.`. I see there are more up to date versions to 3.12.16 but nothing in the release notes mentions this added capability. The same exact query I am running works successfully in the snowflake UI.

Comment: Can you provide the exact query and how you are executing it through JDBC?

Answer (score 2):

I had no problem using `EXPLAIN` and the Snowflake JDBC driver 3.12.8:

```py
print(sc._jvm.net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils.getClientInfoString())

x=sc._jvm.net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils.runQuery(sfOptions, 'explain select * from numbers limit 10')
cols = x.getMetaData().getColumnNames()
print(cols)
while(x.next()):
  print([x.getString(i) for i in range(1, 1+cols.size())])
```

The results show that I'm using the specified JDBC version (through PySpark) and the results of the `EXPLAIN` query:

```
 {
 "spark.version" : "2.4.4",
 "spark.snowflakedb.version" : "2.8.1",
 "spark.app.name" : "Simple App",
 "scala.version" : "2.11.12",
 "java.version" : "1.8.0_242",
 "snowflakedb.jdbc.version" : "3.12.8"
}
['step', 'id', 'parent', 'operation', 'objects', 'alias', 'expressions', 'partitionsTotal', 'partitionsAssigned', 'bytesAssigned']
[None, None, None, 'GlobalStats', None, None, None, '1', '1', '512']
['1', '0', None, 'Result', None, None, 'NUMBERS.X', None, None, None]
['1', '1', '0', 'Limit', None, None, 'rowCount: 10', None, None, None]
['1', '2', '1', 'TableScan', 'TEMP.PUBLIC.NUMBERS', None, 'X', '1', '1', '512']
```

For further community debugging, you'll need to paste your code to check what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

The explain query can be executed via Snowflake  JDBC connector :

Example:

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("explain SELECT top  5 * from SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF10.ORDERS where O_ORDERDATE between '1992-01-01' and '1992-12-31'");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++ ) {
      String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
      System.out.println("name :" + name +" size :" + rsmd.getColumnDisplaySize(i) );
    }
```

O/p:

name :id size :10
name :parent size :10
name :operation size :16777216
name :objects size :16777216
name :alias size :16777216
name :expressions size :16777216
name :partitionsTotal size :39
name :partitionsAssigned size :39
name :bytesAssigned size :39

Thanks,
Sujan Ghosh

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).